# Why use setter when you can assign massively using a method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I found out that I can assign data to a property using set or a method.

```dart
class Human {
  String name, address;
  
  set rewriteName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  set rewriteAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
  
  void rewrite(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }
  
  String introduction() => "Name is $name. I live in $address";
  
  Human(this.name, this.address);
}
```

I tried to assign some data using both way, and method looks more efficient than using setter, since its only need just one call to change everything:

```dart
Human human = Human('stacker', 'baghdad');

// using method
human.rewrite('overflow', 'new york');

// using setter
human.rewriteName = "Hooman";
human.rewriteAddress = "jakarta";
```

my question is why using a setter instead of method?

Comment: Different designs have different use cases. Asking why one is better is opinionated and off-topic here on SO. There is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: of course, I never intended to say some approach is good or wrong, but since there are many ways to do one thing, I'm just curious on how one is existing in that programming language since you already have the other method you can apply e.g. for me, using arrow method for a short and simple way, and normal function for a code that require many lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the targets of getters and setters are made private so they're not directly accessible from outside of the file or library.

```
class Business {
  String name, _address;
  double lat, long;
  bool coordsCalculated = false;
  Map propertyRecords = {};
  
  get address {
    return _address;
  }
  
  set address(String address) {
    if (address == _address) return; // Nothing changed;
    _address = address;
    // API call to calculate lat/log
    APICall(onSuccess: (data) {
      lat = data.lat;
      long = data.long;
      coordsCalculated = true;
    });
  }
  
  void rewrite(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }
  
  String summary() {
    if (coordsCalculated) return "Business name is $name, here's a link to the map!";
    return "Business name is $name, at $_address.";
  }
  
  Human(this.name, String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

The user of the class feels like they're using a normal property, but it does other silent things.

Methods can do this too, yes, but this can feel cleaner.

Importantly, getters and setters cannot be asynchronous which definitely can give methods an advantage, but there are plenty of valid uses.

Getters and setters are also easier to read, when being used. Less parentheses are always a good thing.

You certainly don't need to always use them, or use them when they do nothing but set the variable, but they can be nice.

In one of my Widgets, I have a getter that looks something like

```
FileState get fileState => FileUploaderKey.currentState!. widget.file.state;
```

It's so much easier to read this way. It gets the current state of the file, always, whereas

```
FileState fileState = FileUploaderKey.currentState!.widget.file.state;
```

Only saves the current state, but doesn't change with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically about what the usage looks like, a method call with a parameter vs. what looks like an assignment to a property. From Dart.dev's [*Effective Dart: Design*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-use-setters-for-operations-that-conceptually-change-properties)

> DO use setters for operations that conceptually change properties.
>
> *Linter rule: `use_setters_to_change_properties`*
>
> Deciding between a setter versus a method is similar to deciding between a getter versus a method. In both cases, the operation should be “field-like”.
>
> For a setter, “field-like” means:
>
> - The operation takes a single argument and does not produce a result value.
> - The operation changes some state in the object.
> - The operation is idempotent. Calling the same setter twice with the same value should do nothing the second time as far as the caller is concerned. Internally, maybe you’ve got some cache invalidation or logging going on. That’s fine. But from the caller’s perspective, it appears that the second call does nothing.

In your example you're comparing a method that changes two properties with two separate setters. You'd use the method if it's essential that the two properties both be updated at the same time, as a single conceptual operation. If the properties are independent (and otherwise meet the criteria above), you might use setters instead (if you need to do something when they're set; otherwise, simple data fields might make more sense).